# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException when using multiple transaction managers in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, eclipselink

Am using Spring Integration XML configuration for polling some database tables and then doing some processing. Everything was working fine, until we introduced multiple data sources. After that we are getting **intermittent** `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` exceptions.

Problem is we dont know from which `poller` is this exception coming (we are using xml based configuration), since we have a lot of pollers. Since the stack trace shows the `AbstractPollingEndpoint.java`, we looked at all the pollers and verified that the `transaction-manager` is set properly.

Code:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerSec" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactorySecondary"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSec" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.tmpdao" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactorySecondary" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagerSec" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" primary="true" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${spring.persistence.unitname}" />
        <property name="persistenceProvider" ref="eclipsePP" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" primary="false" id="entityManagerFactorySecondary">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSec"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${spring.secondary.persistence.unitname}" />
        <property name="persistenceProvider" ref="eclipsePPSec" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider" id="eclipsePP" />
<bean class="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider" id="eclipsePPSec" />

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="txSyncFactory">
        <int:before-commit channel="updateEntityChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="procStateAdapter"  channel="inProcStateChannel"
                    entity-manager="entityManagerFactory"
                    auto-startup="true"
                    jpa-query="select <SqlQuery> order by en.lastUpdatedTime"
                    max-results="10"
                    >
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-rate="10" >
            <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" transaction-manager="transactionManager" synchronization-factory="txSyncFactory"/>
        </int:poller>
    </int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

```
2019-10-13 07:51:16,625 [task-scheduler-5] ERROR o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler:handleMessageInternal:192 - org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,transactionManagerSec
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:368)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy409.toString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:141)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there any way to find out the `id` of the poller that is at the beginning of the `AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run` from the stack below so we can debug this further?

Or anything else that is missing from our config for multiple data source.

Comment: your main problem is you have two beans **transactionManager** and **transactionManagerSec**  for **JpaTransactionManager**, you need to define one bean as primary **<bean primary="true|false"/>**

Comment: Starting with version `5.2` we log the whole `BeanDefinition` for the component when exception happens: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2748. So, such an information must appear in logs for that `PollingConsumer` instance.

Answer (score 2):

In your stacktrace it can be seen that :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected 
single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,transactionManagerSec
```

So the issue is that spring finds two qualifying beans for autowiring. Try setting one of your bean as primary using the attribute as @Shailesh suggested :

```
<bean primary="true|false"/>
```

or use a qualifier to set the two transaction beans apart and then specify which transaction manager to be used in code like :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <qualifier value="transactionManagerOne"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerSec" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactorySecondary"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSec" />
        <qualifier value="transactionManagerSecond"/>
</bean>
```

and when you want to use a particular transaction manager specify it using the annotation like :

```
@Transactional("transactionManagerOne")
```

Note: You could configure this via xml as well

> You can use the value attribute of the @Transactional annotation to
>   optionally specify the identity of the PlatformTransactionManager to
>   be used. This can either be the bean name or the qualifier value of
>   the transaction manager bean.The default  target
>   bean name, transactionManager, is still used if no specifically
>   qualified PlatformTransactionManager bean is found.

Official [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional)

Comment: We have already taken care of that. There are two Eclipselink Jpa Auto configuration files, one having the `@Primary` annotation. Ill update the question with that detail.

Comment: @KhushbuTry using `@Transactional` in code to specify the transaction manager to be used.

Comment: But then why is the problem intermittent? It comes once in a while. Most of the time it works. That is why we wanted to find out from which `Spring Integration poller` this exception is coming, so we can debug only that `poller`

Comment: @KhushbuI won't be able to determine that with the available information.Perhaps you could add more logs to the code and test it to identify the path which causes this issue and share the same with us